# Error on authentication when using passport package on laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Hello Everyone i am using the passport package for authentication in laravel but i got the error "Unauthenticated" when i am using on postman.

```
token_type: Bearer
email:mhd.kashif1@gmail.com
access_token:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImEzODBiNDhlYWU4OTU0NGZlMGYyMjViMWEzZWIyMGQ3OTZlN2Y1Y2RjNjBkMDJhM2MzZTA5ZjIzN2Y5NmNkZjgzZTU4ODkyOTE1MjY4MjRiIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI0IiwianRpIjoiYTM4MGI0OGVhZTg5NTQ0ZmUwZjIyNWIxYTNlYjIwZDc5NmU3ZjVjZGM2MGQwMmEzYzNlMDlmMjM3Zjk2Y2RmODNlNTg4OTI5MTUyNjgyNGIiLCJpYXQiOjE1Njg3OTE1NTQsIm5iZiI6MTU2ODc5MTU1NCwiZXhwIjoxNTcwMDg3NTU0LCJzdWIiOiIxNjkiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.sRIVRrFLb9AFrE1oMd5njmkyjWkhgtA-pM6czmTnieDN020n75-r4FL9jNnXC5tTuPJcvm0o-xiy4nOy8rMeaq0OMr0Kr0kcM0RHiSVnNXAfObR1Iy23z5zXMQf_d1kuo-8NX_1ltpZ3FfskzbwVLffYLT6TLR_pIeqBTpTD8jXQyfq8V2yNk7jlH51nZvZbeJJCIaeP9DAqNYmYPOnV5D9Xbzmrx4dXDA0lyIa8Lksz3SvF56JT6xsCf3fjW1uy91nGyfGyCXSF-7bqtkfp2wTlDMW66c43HNMblqfjdPJKOQkwD5Z_rMPCCuOepnzqqShsUdCOWFh2YML-Fg8CXKJ3Lz-rRN_Oj_c-ZFMKyp9cvKht5fDa7Mkjou8m8zG3GCLlsjmU7OMjDNkgXHr-GHh0PNV38lcgz3R3_ZpS_RKzvw3LYOVmBFJP9GvwDLfFMP7Vh2S8GtuG12VfSuyP5e0iK4EMnBPaptXTfeLO7Dz0VGQVzWxYRltef415bVtWMrjJ-dii_BEpJorGINEr0BdTsJoIeKGXAjPsPCQD5MZf3gTM5fE3tdD6ICIrIIczZoss-QPgV-LYn-RMqOeSLMeC-s_ZB1X1MnyHGz8gbTl_QHnnyHJPo3PbkKHcGrW20OwL-l1Rw5rW8zw5vqb0Iy1g7hp1_Yp5eU_MrAIA6l0

device_type:android
device_id:762ead278b86a114
device_token:faS3KB_cjvY:APA91bE5c9Jg2u9mNNWLcw_pWF78Z1wpyBl11GUV8kczaUWQwj5w0mG-KecoXoLgPdcbpQbEcNRvydtNVR1BESHBNz9-WjlSO3daCF-VFqXoG9ap29HMrmgjyS-qvJsLIIqy0TTLx88Z
Accept:application/json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel passport expects an `Authorization` header when authenticating so you need to concatenate `Bearer` with the `access_token` in the request headers of postman

```php
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImEzODBiNDhlYWU4OTU0NGZlMGYyMjViMWEzZWIyMGQ3OTZlN2Y1Y2RjNjBkMDJhM2MzZTA5ZjIzN2Y5NmNkZjgzZTU4ODkyOTE1MjY4MjRiIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI0IiwianRpIjoiYTM4MGI0OGVhZTg5NTQ0ZmUwZjIyNWIxYTNlYjIwZDc5NmU3ZjVjZGM2MGQwMmEzYzNlMDlmMjM3Zjk2Y2RmODNlNTg4OTI5MTUyNjgyNGIiLCJpYXQiOjE1Njg3OTE1NTQsIm5iZiI6MTU2ODc5MTU1NCwiZXhwIjoxNTcwMDg3NTU0LCJzdWIiOiIxNjkiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.sRIVRrFLb9AFrE1oMd5njmkyjWkhgtA-pM6czmTnieDN020n75-r4FL9jNnXC5tTuPJcvm0o-xiy4nOy8rMeaq0OMr0Kr0kcM0RHiSVnNXAfObR1Iy23z5zXMQf_d1kuo-8NX_1ltpZ3FfskzbwVLffYLT6TLR_pIeqBTpTD8jXQyfq8V2yNk7jlH51nZvZbeJJCIaeP9DAqNYmYPOnV5D9Xbzmrx4dXDA0lyIa8Lksz3SvF56JT6xsCf3fjW1uy91nGyfGyCXSF-7bqtkfp2wTlDMW66c43HNMblqfjdPJKOQkwD5Z_rMPCCuOepnzqqShsUdCOWFh2YML-Fg8CXKJ3Lz-rRN_Oj_c-ZFMKyp9cvKht5fDa7Mkjou8m8zG3GCLlsjmU7OMjDNkgXHr-GHh0PNV38lcgz3R3_ZpS_RKzvw3LYOVmBFJP9GvwDLfFMP7Vh2S8GtuG12VfSuyP5e0iK4EMnBPaptXTfeLO7Dz0VGQVzWxYRltef415bVtWMrjJ-dii_BEpJorGINEr0BdTsJoIeKGXAjPsPCQD5MZf3gTM5fE3tdD6ICIrIIczZoss-QPgV-LYn-RMqOeSLMeC-s_ZB1X1MnyHGz8gbTl_QHnnyHJPo3PbkKHcGrW20OwL-l1Rw5rW8zw5vqb0Iy1g7hp1_Yp5eU_MrAIA6l0
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#passing-the-access-token)